Why does KGDB stop at audit_filter_rules immediately after connecting instead of stopping at kgdb_breakpoint?
Why does KGDB stop at audit_filter_rules immediately after connecting instead of stopping at kgdb_breakpoint?
root@us22host-virtual-machine:/home/us22host/linux-5.15.89# gdb vmlinux
(gdb) set serial baud 115200
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyS0
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyS0
warning: multi-threaded target stopped without sending a thread-id, using first non-exited thread
[Switching to Thread 4294967294]
0xffffffff811df804 in audit_filter_rules (tsk=0x202, rule=<optimized out>, ctx=0xffffffff82228d40, name=0xffffc9001ddd7d68, 
    state=0xffffffffffffffff, task_creation=<optimized out>) at kernel/auditsc.c:760
760         *state = AUDIT_STATE_DISABLED;


I have tried methods such as setting the baud rate, checking if /dev/ttyS0 on both virtual machines is connected, and building the kernels of both machines with the same version.
